# Python list index error - out of range, basically I want to loop through each element in all 3 lists

Tags: python, list

Python list index error - out of range, basically I want to loop through each element in all 3 lists

```
day=[15,27,3]

month=['Jan','Dec','Jun']

year=[2013,2002,2010]

for d,m,y in [day,month,year]:

     myDatefunction(d,m,y)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you will have seen, you are iterating the wrong way across those values:

```
>>> for d, m, y in [day, month, year]:
    print d, m, y


15 27 3
Jan Dec Jun
2013 2002 2010
```

This is because, on each iteration, you are unpacking a single source list to `d`, `m` and `y` - this would fail, except that you have as many source lists as they have elements in them. To transpose the lists, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> for d, m, y in zip(day, month, year):
    print d, m, y


15 Jan 2013
27 Dec 2002
3 Jun 2010
```

If you want all combinations, you can do this simply and efficiently with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for d, m, y in product(day, month, year):
    print d, m, y


15 Jan 2013
15 Jan 2002
15 Jan 2010
15 Dec 2013
15 Dec 2002
15 Dec 2010
15 Jun 2013
15 Jun 2002
15 Jun 2010
27 Jan 2013
27 Jan 2002
27 Jan 2010
27 Dec 2013
27 Dec 2002
27 Dec 2010
27 Jun 2013
27 Jun 2002
27 Jun 2010
3 Jan 2013
3 Jan 2002
3 Jan 2010
3 Dec 2013
3 Dec 2002
3 Dec 2010
3 Jun 2013
3 Jun 2002
3 Jun 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over all elements in all lists if you rename the lists by adding (s) to their names :)

```
for year in years:
  for month in months:
    for day in days:
```

zip() requires the length of all lists to be the same which is likely not the case here so a plain loop in loop is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the entries use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> day=[15,27,3]
>>> month=['Jan','Dec','Jun']
>>> year=[2013,2002,2010]
>>> for d, m, y in zip(day, month, year):
    print d, m, y

15 Jan 2013
27 Dec 2002
3 Jun 2010
```